# Debounce and buffer an rxjs subscription

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I have a message queue processor that feeds messages to a service...

```js
q.on("message", (m) => {
  service.create(m)
    .then(() => m.ack())
    .catch(() => n.nack())
})
```

The service uses an RxJS Observable and subscription to `debounceTime()` those requests.

```js
class Service {
  constructor() {
    this.subject = new Subject()
    this.subject.debounceTime(1000)
      .subscribe(({ req, resolve, reject }) =>
        someOtherService.doWork(req)
          .then(() => resolve())
          .catch(() => reject())
      )
  }

  create(req) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      this.subject.next({
        req,
        resolve,
        reject
      })
    )
  }
}
```

The issue is that only the debounced request gets ackd/nackd.  How can I ensure that the subscription also resolves/rejects the other requests?  `bufferTime()` gets me a part of the way there, but it does not reset the timeout duration on each call to `next()`.

Comment: You could use `buffer` with a closing notifier built from `debounceTime`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50402139/6680611) for the basic mechanism. That will give you all of the emissions within the denounce duration and you can do with them whatever you want.

Comment: Since that solution merges two streams, how would you incorporate that approach here?

Comment: You can just leave the merge out. It's the notified buffer that's common - with `debounceTime` instead of `auditTime` for the notifier. I can write you an answer soon; was on mobile, earlier.

Comment: I see what you mean now...tried the approach and seems to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `debounceTime` operator that you are currently using can be used to create an observable that can notify `buffer` of when the current buffer should be closed.

Then, `buffer` will emit an array of the messages that were received whilst debouncing and you can do with them whatever you want:

```js
this.subject = new Subject();
const closingNotifier = this.subject.debounceTime(1000);
this.subject.buffer(closingNotifier).subscribe(messages => {
  const last = messages.length - 1;
  messages.forEach(({ req, resolve, reject }, index) => {
    if (index === last) {
      /* whatever you are doing, now, with the debounced message */
    } else {
      /* whatever you need to do with the ignored messages */
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: So why no `bufferDebounce` operator? I made the mistake of doing `buffer(100)` and I only discovered by accident that I was getting an empty array every 100ms for all eternity! I would have thought `buffer(100)` would have emitted nothing if empty. I assume this version isn't running a callback if nothing comes in for 10 seconds.

Comment: I suppose it's because someone else would ask for `bufferAudit` or `bufferThrottle`, etc. and any of them can be built out of `buffer` and a notifier.

Comment: Well I'm just glad I discovered that `buffer(0)` is not a good idea before it was too late or confusing! Kind of like using `shareReplay()` when you really meant to put `shareReplay(1)` ;-)

Answer (score 11):

For those who are looking for a RXJS 6 Solution, I created a custom operator to behave like a `debounce()` + `buffer()` as in the previous answer.

I called it `bufferDebounce` and the snippet in Typescript with Type inference is here:

```ts
import { Observable, OperatorFunction } from 'rxjs'
import { buffer, debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators'

type BufferDebounce = <T>(debounce: number) => OperatorFunction<T, T[]>;
const bufferDebounce: BufferDebounce = debounce => source =>
  new Observable(observer =>
    source.pipe(buffer(source.pipe(debounceTime(debounce)))).subscribe({
      next(x) {
        observer.next(x);
      },
      error(err) {
        observer.error(err);
      },
      complete() {
        observer.complete();
      },
    }),
  );
```

You can test its behavior in this example to check if this suits you https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-buffer-debounce