# How to add a limit to buffer and debounce in RxJs subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs

I would like to achieve the following using RxJs:

1. Group message that are within ~200ms of the previous message
2. Emit group of messages when no new messages have been received within 250ms
3. Emit group of messages when group reaches 10 items.

Thanks to several other questions on SO, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50515357/debounce-and-buffer-an-rxjs-subscription), it's quite easy to implement 1 and 2 using a combination of `buffer` and `debounceTime`, like so:

```js
const subject$ = new Subject<number>();

// Create the debounce
const notifier$ = subject$.pipe(
  debounceTime(250)
);

// Subscribe to the subject using buffer and debounce
subject$
  .pipe(
    buffer(notifier$)
  )
  .subscribe(value => console.log(value));

// Add a number to the subject every 200ms untill it reaches 10
interval(200)
  .pipe(
    takeWhile(value => value <= 10),
  )
  .subscribe(value => subject$.next(value));
```

Here messages are buffered as long as they're emitted within 200ms of the last one. If it takes more than 200ms a new buffer is started. However, if messages keep coming in under 200ms the messages could be buffered forever. That's why I want to add a hard limit on the buffer size.

I created an example at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-buffer-debounce) to demonstrate the buffer debounce. But I can't figure out how to limit the buffer so that it emits when it reaches 10 items as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could create another notifier to limit the number of item (eg. with `elementAt`), use the notifier that emits first (with `race`) and apply this recursively (with `expand`):

```
const notifierDebouncing$ = subject$.pipe(
  debounceTime(PERIOD),
  take(1)
);

const notifierLimiting$ = subject$.pipe(
  elementAt(AMOUNT - 1)
);

const notifier$ = interval(0).pipe(
  take(1),
  expand(_ => race(notifierLimiting$, notifierDebouncing$))
);

subject$
  .pipe(buffer(notifier$))
  .subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

What do you think?

Here is an example, based on your demo app: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-buffer-debounce-cf4qjy
(open the console, then move the cursor for 2000ms and stop for 500ms)

Comment: Brilliant answer and works flawlessly but I'm left scratching my head on how it works though. I tried tinkering around by replacing interval(0) + take(1) with of(0) thought it'd work the same but it didn't. It messes up the max buffer size. Can you explain why 'of' doesn't work here?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just filter it if its 10th item? Maybe i misunderstood your question.

```js
    interval(this.interval)
      .pipe(
        filter(value => value % 10 === 0),
        takeWhile(value => value <= this.amount),
      )
      .subscribe(value => this.subject$.next(value));
  }
```

Comment: I believe that would only give me every 10th message. Not quite what I need. I updated the question to clarify my goal.