# Does rxjs offer a better way of solving a debounced buffer implementation

Tags: angular, rxjs, buffer, debouncing

For an angular application I have a situation where the container-component is resolving queries made by various child-component widgets in a dashboard. For performance I want to buffer these queries so I can combine them into a single request to the server. Because each widget has its own loading process the moment it will send its query can vary.

The functionality I want to achieve is that for any query that is emitted by one of the widgets I want to wait 200 milliseconds for any other widget queries to be emitted while making sure that all queries in that sequence are buffered.

I currently have the following approach to solving this:

```
const queryRecord$ = new Subject<void>();

queries$
  .pipe(
    tap(() => queryRecord$.next()),
    buffer(queryRecord$.pipe(debounceTime(200))),
    mergeMap(queries => fetcher.fetch(flatten(queries))),
  )
  .subscribe(metrics => {
    // do something
  });
```

I cant help but feel that having to bring in an extra subject is not right, yet I can't think of another way of doing it either.

Can anyone help me with a suggestion for a better approach to getting the same outcome?

NOTE: I have already tried `bufferTime` but that is not exactly what I want because it'll keep on running the 200ms interval.

Comment: Isn't that the exact functionality of [debounceTime](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/debouncetime)?

Comment: I comes close, but debounceTime will only return me the last emitted query, yet I wish to collect all the queries from that sequence.

Comment: Ah, I missed that part. Then yes, you will need two observables, one being the actual buffer and second being notifier for that buffer to close. You can wrap it nicely into custom operator though, e.g. something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62598663/4550158)

Comment: That link is probably what I was after. Thanks a lot!